# Using Tencent Cloud COS to upload files in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

Failed to upload files using Tencent Cloud COS in the main process of Electron

result:
"code":"EPROTO","name":"EPROTO","message":"write EPROTO 640892744:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242:\n"